# how to plot labels TFRecords in histogram

Tags: tensorflow

Hello i have many files of TFRecords. i use python tensorflow and  want to plot in one histogram all labels.
TFRecords  is pair of (image,label)
so how i can extract all the labels  ?
i have try to extract labels and have success plot several batches

```
all_label = []
for image, label in ds_train.take(10):
    all_label.append(label)

 sns.distplot(all_label)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this.

```
import re
#import pdftotext
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from io import StringIO


def convert_pdf_to_txt(path):
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
    fp = open(path, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0
    caching = True
    pagenos=set()

    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password,caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)

    text = retstr.getvalue()

    fp.close()
    device.close()
    retstr.close()
    return text



with open('C:\\Users\\Finance10K.txt') as f:
    clean_cont = f.read().splitlines()


clean_cont


doc=[i.replace('\xe2\x80\x9c','') for i in clean_cont ]
doc=[i.replace('\xe2\x80\x9d','') for i in doc ]
doc=[i.replace('\xe2\x80\x99s','') for i in doc ]

docs = [x for x in doc if x != ' ']
docss = [x for x in docs if x != '']


doc

docs

docss


financedoc=[re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]+", " ", s) for s in docss]
financedoc


from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer,TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.decomposition import LatentDirichletAllocation
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
#%pylab
#%matplotlib inline
from sklearn.feature_extraction.stop_words import ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS


vect=CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,1),stop_words='english')


fin=vect.fit_transform(financedoc)


fin


pd.DataFrame(fin.toarray(),columns=vect.get_feature_names())


lda=LatentDirichletAllocation(n_components=5)


lda.fit_transform(fin)


lda_dtf=lda.fit_transform(fin)


sorting=np.argsort(lda.components_)[:,::-1]
features=np.array(vect.get_feature_names())

import mglearn
mglearn.tools.print_topics(topics=range(5), feature_names=features,
sorting=sorting, topics_per_chunk=5, n_words=10)


#from __future__ import  print_function
import pyLDAvis
import pyLDAvis.sklearn
pyLDAvis.enable_notebook()


zit=pyLDAvis.sklearn.prepare(lda,fin,vect)


pyLDAvis.show(zit)
```

[image]